# How to extend a plain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, extend

I frequently find myself in the situation where I want to spice up some div with extra behavior. I do this as follows:

```
TimedElementView = function(lane, te) {
    var tev = $("<div class=ui-corner-all></div>")
                .attr("id", nextId("tev"))
                .css({"overflow": "hidden",
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "text-align":"center",
                      "background": "#abc"
                     });

     ...
     return tev};
```

Then everything which would usually be prefixed by `this` gets prefixed by `tev` as in

```
  tev.sublane = function (n,m) {
            this.n = n;
            this.m = m;
            return this;
        };
```

The mixture of `tev` and `this` causes me some headaches. I run into problems, where firebug tells me that `this` is not defined, so I am worried I am totally on the wrong track.

Can anyone shed some light on this (sic!) ? What is the proper way of extending a plain div?

Comment: seriously! can `this` be `undefined`?

Comment: @TamilVendhan - It can if used with `use strict;`

Comment: oh! good to know! I just tried this out in console. But it prints `window` object. `function x() {console.log(this)}; var a; x.call(a);`

Comment: even `'use strict'; x.call(undefined);` prints same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Go & create a JS Fiddle for your problem. Then tell what exactly what are you are trying to achieve ?

What the heck are you trying to achieve in latter block of code ? It doesn't make any sense to me.